# can anyone tell me how to find out the path for '`images`' folder which is inside mywebapp?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have one folder named 'images' which is just inside my web application 'mywebapp'.

**`ie., mywebapp/images`**

I have one java file (not a servlet), **can anyone tell me how to find out the path for '`images`' folder?**

If it would be a servlet, i would have used something like `request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath( path )`

but for a Java file which is inside a web-app, how to find its folder's path?

```
images folder I need to store images in it dynamically!
```

Comment: You are aware that it does not need to be a folder on the file system? A web container can choose to run the web app out of the WAR file without expanding it.

Comment: where is the java file in relation to the image file.  Is the java class compiled and exploded to WEB-ING/classes/..../someClass.class?

Comment: @user2310289 YES, file compiles into WEB-INF/classes

Comment: What do you mean by a "web-app" that is not a servlet?

Comment: "to store images in it dynamically" - If you want to store uploaded or created files I suggest you use a directory outside of your webapp and configure it as well-known absolute path. This way you don't need to worry about losing the images when you need to re-deploy (read: update) your app later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may user [URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) to find path of your file or folder
URL contain [getPath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getPath%28%29) method which return `absolute path` of your file or folder:

```
URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("FILE OR FOLDER NAME");  
System.out.println("Folder path : "+url.getPath());
```

May this will help you.

Comment: Could you please tell where should I keep my folder? I tried keeping 'imgs' folder just inside 'mywebapp/imgs', But getting Nullpointerexception..

Comment: @user3128668 It will only work if you need path of the file inside class folder.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below to find the absolute path of images dir:

```
 String absoluteImagePath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/images";
```

Comment: Iam not in a servlet!

Comment: @user3128668 you can use System.getProperty("user.dir"), to get the root folder of your project.

Answer (score 0):

As the compiled class is in WEB-INF/classes if you do not have to the servlet context you could open the file at ../../images/picture.jpg

Comment: Is that not possible to get a web application root path inside some java file which is not  a servlet? My idea is: if i get webapp root path, then I can just directly use webapprootpath/images

Comment: @user3128668 No it is not possible to have context path directly inside java file (which is not servlet).

Comment: of course you could always pass this information in as a parameter.

Comment: @Yagnesh Then how  to find 'images' folder which is inside 'mywebapp'?

Comment: @Yagnesh Could you please tell where should I keep my folder? I tried keeping 'imgs' folder just inside 'mywebapp/imgs', But getting Nullpointerexception